# card effect how to show for e.g. 3 secs?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am quite new 
I am displaying 5 cards, one is Ace. I want to show it for 1 sec(set image at start) and the immediate hide it (change image to other). How to do it ? How to get id of a button that has Ace ??
I think it must be done in 
- (void)viewDidLoad method , or maybe I am mistaken ?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far and point us to the exact problem. Which of the approaches you tried didn't work?

Comment: Is this really a question about XCode?

Comment: yes I am programming in xCode an application for iPhone. So far I don't know how to get the id of a button that has this Ace... If I had  the id I would set background for this given button and after 1 sec hide it.

Comment: Also I do not have the code because I have 3 buttons(that are cards) added through storyboards and in my ViewController.m there is no refference to them... If I could give the attribute for every button I would simply check if e.g. if (button_1 == is_Ace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this, is to create the UIButton with reserved title, same as the card.
Example :

```
// I hope you are maintaining an array for the cards
    NSArray *arrCard = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ace",@"1" ............., nil];

UIButton *btnCard = [[UIButton alloc]init];
     btnCard = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [btnCard setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [btnCard setFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,40,80)]; // Keep this portion in the loop.
   [btnCard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrCard objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateReserved];

// For image of the card
    [btnCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     [self.view addSubview:btnCard];

    if ( [[btnCard titleForState:UIControlStateReserved] isEqualToString: @"Ace"])
    {
    // To keep it displayed for one second
              [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0.f options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone)
                             animations:
             ^{
                 [btnCard setAlpha:0];
// Then make it disappear Or remove this line to hold the btnCard in image
             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished)
             {
                 [btnCard removeFromSuperview];
    // Or perform any other function
             }];

    }
```

Lemme know if you get stuck anywhere else.

Comment: I've got an error when compiling with [self.view addSubView:btnCard];    :No @Interface for UIView declers the selector addSubView.   + I understand that here : for(j=0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        [btnCard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrCard objectAtIndex:j]] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
    
    
     // For image of the card
     [btnCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:j]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
I declear the title for all 3 buttons ? If e.g. I have 5 buttons how can I be sure which ones were titled. ?

Comment: Use [self.view addSubview:btnCard]     edited the answer..

Comment: You should mark the answer as Correct, to remove it from Unanswered questions.

Comment: I only meant this one: [self.view addSubview:btnCard]. Cose when I Run the project I got the 1 Thread: SIGABRT

Comment: okkk, I was not expecting you to copy the copy the code word-to-word. Anyways, keep trying and let me know if you reach any dead-end.

Comment: is it possible to set title from storyboards ??   Because now I get here: btnCard titleForState:forState:UIControlStateReserved Use of undecleared identifier forState

Comment: corrections made. CHECK !

Comment: ok now it compiles ok , but when run : 1 Thread: SIGABRT.   Hitesh can you explain to me how those titles are being assigned to the round rec buttons added from storyboards ?? I couldn't find this in attributes inspector.

Comment: UIButton allows for several types of control states, but Attributes inspector uses only UIControlStateNormal, the rest of them need to be accessed programmatically.

Comment: Again made changes to the code, CHECK. Now the SIGABRT wont be present. Sorry for the TYPO errors tho, I got my own work on my head :P

Comment: no problem :) I still got the error but it might be me cose my first part looks as follow:

Comment: NSArray *arrCard = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Ace",@"1",@"2", nil];
UIButton *btnCard = [[UIButton alloc]init];
NSArray *arrImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown0.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown1.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown2.jpg"],
                          nil];
    int j;
    for(j=0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        [btnCard setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrCard objectAtIndex:j]] forState:UIControlStateReserved];
     [btnCard setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImages objectAtIndex:j]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }

Comment: Check the code not, EDITED !! You have been copying the code, please write the missing code, setFrame methods, etc.